# Video Player not displaying inside of collapsible div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a video player to display a reel for people on a website I am making, though it will not display if the div is set to display:none; and is then toggled with jquerys .slideToggle()

This is the toggle code.

```
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('#containerDiv').slideToggle();
    });
```

This is the video player I am using: http://codecanyon.net/item/ultimate-video-player/7694071

HTML:

```
    <div class="button">
        <span class="title">Title</span><span class="name">Name</span>
    </div>
    <div id="containerDiv" class="Reel"><!--There is a bunch of omitted code here--></div>
```

Its should also be noted that the player itself is loaded through javascript and is not part of the original DOM structure, and I think his is why I am having problems.

Comment: What kind of video player? Flash, HTML5, Silverlight, etc.?

Comment: The link is there, but its HTML5 and javascript, though will fallback to flash for older browsers.  I am testing it in the newest versions of Opera and Chrome.

Comment: Maybe scenario with `display: none` is not handled by the player itself. You can try to test if it works with `visibility: hedden` instead or hide the player after the it's loaded.

Comment: The video is actually loaded through a JavaScript function, so I cant directly edit the style of the player once its loaded.  But It should be mentioned that when I load the window with the Element visible, and then use slideToggle to hide it, it works fine.  I have tried to use $('#contianerDiv").load to hide it, but this also make it fail to display.

Comment: I found on that player's page that its API contains some event listeners that are described in the documentation, so maybe there is  `loaded` event of the video player itself and You could use it to hide the player after it's initialized.

Comment: I didn't find anything too useful in the API, though I'm not a pro at JavaScript.